# How can the Wix Installer distinguish target builds?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, wix, wix3.8

My C# project in Visual Studio will be installed via Wix. I have two target builds: Demo and Release. I want to distinguish these builds and add the suffix 'Demo' to the name of the product:

```
#if Demo
  <?define Suffix = "(Demo)"?>
#endif

<Product [...] Name="MyApp $(var.Suffix)" [...] >
```

How can I make work this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a solution by my self. I can distinguish between the demo and the release using `var.ProjectName.Configuration` and Wix´s preprocessor.

- [Project Reference Variables](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/votive/votive_project_references.html)
- [Preprocessor](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/overview/preprocessor.html)

This is my switch:

```
<?if $(var.ProjectName.Configuration) = Demo ?>
    <?define Suffix = "(Demo)" ?>
<?else ?>
    <?define Suffix = "" ?>
<?endif ?>
```

Adding the suffix (Demo) to my Product:

```
<Product [...] Name="MyApp $(var.Suffix)" [...] >
```

Answer (score 3):

With the following code you can define `producttarget` WiX variable based on `Configuration` MSBuild property:

```
<!-- Somewhere in .wixproj -->
<PropertyGroup>
    <DefineConstants Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' ">$(DefineConstants);producttarget= (Demo)</DefineConstants>
    <DefineConstants Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Release' ">$(DefineConstants);producttarget=</DefineConstants>
</PropertyGroup>
```

And then use `producttarget` in your `Product` declaration:

```
<Product Id="*"
         Name="SetupProject1$(var.producttarget)"
         Language="1033"
         Version="1.0.0.0"
         Manufacturer="Manufacturer1"
         UpgradeCode="41169d90-ca08-49bc-b87b-4b74f1f50d0e">
```